# videoview in android activity takes very long time to load

Tags: android, android-activity, android-videoview

I have an android activity where I load a video into a videoview and play it. The problem is when I launch the activity the screen is black for about 15 seconds before anything appears and the video plays. Here's my code.

```
public class welcomevideo extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcomevideo);
    VideoView vidView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myVideo);
    String vidadress = "**";
    Uri vidUri = Uri.parse(vidadress);
    vidView.setVideoURI(vidUri);
    MediaController vidControl = new MediaController(this);
    vidView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            Intent setIntent = new Intent(welcomevideo.this,AllGameslistActivity.class);
            startActivity(setIntent);
            finish();
        }
    });
    vidControl.setAnchorView(vidView);
    vidView.setMediaController(vidControl);
    vidView.start();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_welcomevideo, menu);
    return true;
}
public void yoe(View v) {
    Intent e = new Intent(welcomevideo.this,AllGameslistActivity.class);
    startActivity(e);
    finish();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent setIntent = new Intent(welcomevideo.this,AllGameslistActivity.class);
    startActivity(setIntent);
    finish();
}
@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    //closing transition animations
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_open_scale, R.anim.ctivity_close_translate);
}
```

}

Comment: Is it a online video URL?

Comment: May be video is buffering due to network speed.

Comment: First it doesn't show anything, the screen is black, then it loads the video pretty quickly once it appears

Comment: Sorry I dont know. SetOnPrepareListener and see whether preparing takes more time.

Comment: Did you solve that problem? It is happening with me too.